# upload default image if user didn't upload image php

Tags: php, sql

I created a table and fetched data from database... But if user did not upload any image then how can i upload default image in this table.

Thank you in advance.

Below is table that fetched data from database.

This is database connection:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","krishna","krishna","krishna");

    if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ?>
```

Below is table that fetched data from database

```
<table id="contact-list" border='1' class="tblListForm">
    <thead>
        <tr class="listheader">
             <th><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select_all"></th>
             <th> id </th>
             <th> First name </th>
             <th> Last name </th>
             <th> User Name </th>
             <th> Gender </th>
             <th> Date Of Birth </th>
             <th> Email-Id </th>
             <th> Mobile Number </th>
             <th> Image </th>
             <th> Delete </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

 <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM employe");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        // Change Date Format
    $date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/','-,$row['date_of_birth'])));
    ?>
    <!-- fetching data from database --> 
    <tbody>`enter code here`
     <tr>
        <td><input type ='checkbox' value="<?=$row['select']?>"="<?=$row['select']?>" class="allcheckbox">
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['firstname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $date;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['mobile_no'];?></td>
        <td><img src="image/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td> <!-- this is image that i fetched from my database -->
        <td><form action='delete.php?name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post"'><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"></form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <?php
    }   
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: How you insert image into the table if user upload an image

Comment: Upload an avatar image to your uploads folder. If   $row['image'] is null, then specify the avatar image path. That is the better solution for this

Comment: upload 1 common image in your folder , say profile.png , then check from input request , has file then upload image else , just set default image name $profile='/uploads/profile.png'

Comment: Set default image name in your database table ..if user not upload any image then display that image which name is save in your data base ...save image in your directory

Comment: So. You have a database connection file. Something that looks like a profile page and some JS that does something with checkboxes. Tell me, what exactly does this have to do with image uploads?

Comment: thankuu so much @BimalKumar i got it.....